# Correlated Wiener Process

Tags: black-scholes, monte-carlo, quants, cholesky

I am in trouble with a task:

I have a portfolio of 5 assets, and I Have the correlation among them, with a 5x5 matrix.

Since each asset follows the BS formula: [image], I need to perform a montecarlo simulation, with a number of simulations (N) for instance equal to 10000, for a period of 1 year, with 12 payments (monthly payment).

So I need to simulate the trajectory of each asset, considering the correlation among them. How can I do this? I have seen something regarding the Cholesky decomposition, but I have not understood how do it, since when we simulate the trajectory of each asset, we have a matrix made by: 5 row (asset) and 10000 element inside each row (trajectory each asset)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cholesky decomposition works in the following way: Suppose you have a vector of $n$ independent normal realisations: $Z$. Set the elements of $\Sigma$ to be $\rho_{i,j}$ where $i$ indicates the row and $j$ indicates the column. Obviously $\rho_{i,i}=1$. We set the Cholesky decomposition of $\Sigma$ to be $L$ (a lower triangular matrix) such that $\Sigma=L\cdot L^{\top}$. Then $X=L\cdot Z$ is normally distributed with mean 0 and covariance matrix $\Sigma$.

Functioning R code is for the simple case of $n=2$ with one sample is given below

```
Sigma<-matrix(c(1,0.9,0.9,1),nrow=2)

L<-t(chol(Sigma)) #transpose as R uses upper triangular for cholesky
L%*%t(L) #check


Z<-rnorm(2)
X<-L%*%Z
```

You only have to calculate $L$ once, but have to calculate $Z$ and $X$ once per point on the trajectory.